# php regular expression to replace HREF attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to use php `preg_replace` and `regular expression` to remove all the hyperlink which contain `<a href="#`. Here is what I write, but it doesn't work

```
$newlink = preg_replace('/^<a href="#(.*)" (?:.*?)>(.*)<\/a>/is', '', $link);
```

I want replace these links which as aa `anchor mark`

```
<a href="#part1">go to part1</a>
<a href="#part2">go to part2</a>
<a href="#part3">go to part3</a>
```

to empty value.

Comment: They do not match, because they don't have a space after the second quote mark `"` as required by your regex. But please be very careful if you handle HTML with regular expressions. In almost any case it is not what you want to do but use a proper parser instead.

Comment: Where do you get the input from? I think using an HTML parse and XPath will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks two of all, But both of your answer still not work for me.

I am not good at `regular expression`, I read many documents and write again. maybe this looks ugly, but it work :)

```
$newlink = preg_replace('/(<a href=")#.*?(<\/a>)/is', '', $link);
```

Comment: No need for the capture groups. The regex can be simplified to just: `'/<a href="#.*?<\/a>/is'`

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying that using regular expressions for parsing/modifying HTML documents can be the *wrong* approach. I'd encourage you to check out [DOM Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) if you're doing this for any other modifications.

With that said, making your expression non-greedy (`.*?`) will probably work.

```
$newlink = preg_replace('/^<a href="#(.*?)"[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>/', '', $link);
```

**Note:** This also assumes `href` is the first attribute in all you anchor tags. Which may be a poor assumption.

Answer (score 1):

It's remove only href attribute from html

```
echo preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) href=".*?"/i', '$1', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the href's value, you'll need to use assertions to match it without matching anything else. This regex will only match the URL:

```
/(?<=<a href=")#.*?(?=")/
```

Answer (score 0):

use `/(<a.*?href=([\'"]))(.*?)(\2.*?>)/i` regex

```
<?php 
     $oldLink = '<a href="http://test.com">click this link</a>';
     $res = "http://stackoverflow.com";
     echo $newLink = preg_replace('/(<a.*?href=([\'"]))(.*?)(\2.*?>)/i', '$1'.$res.'$2', $oldLink);    
?>
```

if you wants to test this regex, then you can [here `https://regex101.com/r/mT1sVK/1`](https://regex101.com/r/mT1sVK/1)